# Checking for receipt of UDP Packets on Port

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I am relatively new to UDP. I am trying to write some code in a function that checks if I am receiving data on a UDP port, so I can change an element to show the fact that the system is receiving something. Unfortunately I am constrained to UDP and not TCP, so need a way to show there is some connection alive (basically that the remote program sending the UDP Packets is running). For context, I am trying to read the contents of a system for displaying a flightplan in an aircraft in a flight simulator. The page should update regularly

The below code doesn't throw errors, but I note in the Console Window even though I attempt to clear the data ready for the next message, I constantly seem to get the same data without updating. I clear the array yet the same data is deposited into it! It is definitely changing in the UDP packets, just not in my code. I restart the app and the page updates, so something isn't clearing right. See below code:

```
while (runTolissCapt_Connect) //Keep checking for UDP Incoming
{
    IPAddress servIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(TolissIP);
    var servEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(servIPAddress, TolissPort_Capt);

    if (_TolissCaptUdpClient == null) //If we haven't setup the UdpClient yet
    {
        lbl_Toliss_Conn.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => lbl_Toliss_Conn.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed));

        try
        {
            _TolissCaptUdpClient = new UdpClient(TolissPort_Capt);

            mcdu.SetTolissUpdClient(_TolissCaptUdpClient);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
    
    Byte[] receiveData = _TolissCaptUdpClient.Receive(ref servEndPoint); //Receive data
    string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveData); //Format data

    if (returnData != null) //If we got some data 
    {
        Toliss_Alive = true;
        Console.WriteLine(returnData); //Write UDP message to console
    }
    else
    {
        Toliss_Alive = false;
    }

    Array.Clear(receiveData, 0, receiveData.Length); //Attempt to clear previous UDP message
    returnData = "";

    if (Toliss_Alive) //Change UI to reflect UDP status
        lbl_Toliss_Conn.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => lbl_Toliss_Conn.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen));
    else
        lbl_Toliss_Conn.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => lbl_Toliss_Conn.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed));

    new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(500);
}
```

It is probably simple. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you remove the wait at the end? I suspect because of that you're seeing bufferd messages

Comment: If you get the same data it is probably because the sender send the same data. Note that the concept of "connection", or "receipt" does not exist in UDP. That need to be provided by a protocol on top of UDP. But it sounds like you are integrating with an existing system, so you will need to follow that pre-existing protocol.

Comment: @mtmk That is exactly what was happening! Is there anyway to clear the buffer? Polling every couple of ms is unnecessary, I only need to check every couple of seconds or so

Comment: @JonasH The data was definitely changing as I can see it in another program correctly. It is a problem in my code

Comment: @Horgy receive blocks anyway, why not just don't do the additional wait.?

Comment: Don't keep opening and closing the socket. If the datagram arrives while the socket doesn't exist it will be thrown away. Keep it open for the duration.